# How do I repeat function with onclick?

Tags: javascript

```js
var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = color;
document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

```css
#bg { width: 90px; height: 45px; margin: auto; }
.box { border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 22vh auto; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; }
button { width: 90px; height: 45px; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p id="name"></p>
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <br>
  <button id="button" onclick="location.reload()">Again</button>
</div>
```

I am currently using location.reload() since repeating function with onclick doesn't work. I am making a random color picker. When I click the button, I want the  and  to change. But this only works once. 
How can I repeat function with onclick?

Comment: _I want the and to change._ what does this mean ? Can you please clearly state the problem statement

Comment: just wrap that js code in a function and call the function in `onclick`, like `onclick=changeColor();`

Comment: I want the para and bg to change Sorry I typed wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple wrap your code in a function and call it on `onclick` something like

```js
function changeColor(){
    var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = color;
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;
}

changeColor();
```

```css
 #bg { width: 90px; height: 45px; margin: auto; }
.box { border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 22vh auto; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; }
button { width: 90px; height: 45px; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <p id="name"></p>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <br>
    <button id="button" onclick="changeColor()">Again</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

chenge in html

```
<button id="button" onclick="myfunction()">Again</button>
```

change in javascript

```
function myfunction()
{
        var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = color;
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
myfunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside of function and call it in `onclick` button.

```
var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = color;
document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

```js
    function reload(){
var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = color;
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;}
```

```css
    #bg { width: 90px; height: 45px; margin: auto; }
    .box { border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 22vh auto; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; }
    button { width: 90px; height: 45px; }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    <p id="name"></p>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <br>
    <button id="button" onclick="reload()">Again</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the code into an actual function which can be called over and over.

Make sure to run it once yourself to set the initial random color.

```js
function randomColor() {
    var color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = color;
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
randomColor();
```

```css
#bg { width: 90px; height: 45px; margin: auto; }
    .box { border: 1px solid black; padding: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 22vh auto; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; }
    button { width: 90px; height: 45px; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <p id="name"></p>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <br>
    <button id="button" onclick="randomColor()">Again</button>
    </div>
```